# Is it possible to extract all names of a facebook group and some basics details about who added them?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am the admin of a private Facebook group that we use for business, I would like to extract all the names from the group and the date and person who added them. I'm interested to know is there a possible way to do that ? some ideas or any suggestions ?

about the extraction format, It doesn't actually matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all members names, members id, group description, member role. First generate the login url using facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev:

```
      $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => APP_ID,
      'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4', // or use v2.5 latest version
      ]);

      $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

      $permissions = ['user_managed_groups']; 

      $redirectUrl = 'http://localhost/fbapp.php';
      $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $permissions);

      echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

After generating login url implement the code for response handling and getting required data.

```
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
      setcookie('accessToken',$accessToken);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

    // Get user groups detail
    $requestUserManagedGroups = $fb->request('GET', '/me/groups?fields=members,from');

//Make a batch request
$batch = ['user-groups' => $requestUserLikes];

try {
  $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

for a better view can use this:

```
foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
  if ($response->isError()) {
    $e = $response->getThrownException();
    echo '<p>Error! Facebook SDK Said: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n";
    echo '<p>Graph Said: ' . "\n\n";
    var_dump($e->getResponse());
  } else {
    echo "<p>(" . $key . ") HTTP status code: " . $response->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br />\n";
    echo "Response: " . $response->getBody() . "</p>\n\n";
    echo "<hr />\n\n";
  }
}
```

for group related more better understanding -visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group

and for group members related information visit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members

Comment: but how can I get the name of the admin who added the member ?